# Render EJS view by buttonclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ejs

I'm working on a EJS project and i run into a problem, I want to render pages if the user click on the button.

now the jQuery looks like this:

```
<button onclick="show()" id="addPartial"> add more TestPartial</button>

<div id="addPartialtHere">
</div>

<script>
    function show() {
        $("#addPartialtHere").load("/test");
    }
</script>
```

but it not works, due to load is only load HTML.

I also find https://github.com/tj/ejs/, but is not updated since 2015. Thats why i think it is not the best choice.

One last thing, https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-dynamic-partials, but its not the last update was 4 years before.

Any other suggestion?
Is there any way to render view in another one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with the load method in Jquery it makes ajax call to the server for the page.

And check for the Ajax response in network tab in browser.

If error is cross origin not allowed.

Try adding this code in Node server

```
 app.all('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
 });

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // Handle the get for this route
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that work correctly. One more question: is there any way to concatenate thiese partial? for eg, if 1 hit the button 4 times then render the partial for times.

Comment: Can you clarify it? becouse if i  use this code, it isn't works:
    '$("#addPartialtHere").append(load("/test"));'

Comment: U can do something like this 
var _htmlContent = $.get("/test");
$("#addPartialHere").append(_htmlContent);

Comment: or u can create hidden_element and append that element every time call load

$("#hiddenelem").load("/test");
var _htmlContent = $("#hiddenelem").html();
$("#addPartialHere").append(_htmlContent);

Comment: I select the  "$get()"  solution, with a little modification:
`function addRounds() {
    $.get("/rounds", function (data) {
        alert(data);
        $("#addPartialtHere").append(data);
    })
};`

Answer (score -1):

You  can  try  [handlebarsjs](http://handlebarsjs.com/) or [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/)

Comment: He didn't ask for what template engine to use.

Comment: He ask to  other suggestion as I can see.

Comment: Yes, I want to look for alternative solution too, but i dont want to replace the template engine.

Comment: So could you explain what kind of suggestions  did you need ?